# When to use .then, .done, .fail

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I limit myself to the .ajax method (and NOT to the shortcuts like .get and .load), then should I use the deferred object methods

```
.then, .done, .fail, .when, .reject, .resolve, .always, .promise
```

or the Global Event Handlers:

```
.ajaxSuccess, .ajaxComplete, .ajaxError, .ajaxSetup, .ajaxStart, .ajaxStop,
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use .done() and .fail() for new jQuery AJAX code instead of success and error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931836/should-i-use-done-and-fail-for-new-jquery-ajax-code-instead-of-success-and)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods on a deferred objects (such as can be constructed from a jQuery AJAX request) are executed in relation to that particular deferred. This is quite different from global event handlers, as these will called when ANY AJAX requests. So you will see the same results if you only have one AJAX request on each page, but things will of course be quite different with multiple AJAX requests.

The closer counterpart to the deferred object methods are the `error`, `success`, and `complete` methods which define callbacks for a jQuery AJAX request.

**Example**

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({url:'myapi.json', method:'post'});
```

Now, with `jqxhr`, `$.when(jqxhr).then(…)` is equivalent to `jqxhr.complete(…)`. A similar relationship applies to `resolve` and `success`, also `reject` and `error`.

Comment: OK Michael, thanks!  I guess I'm trying to understand why they've added this new syntax when error, success and complete were already in the language.  Maybe I should look at the version notes.  I just don't know if I should be using one over the other.  I think you're saying to use error, success and complete.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Deferreds can be used not only for AJAX requests, but potentially for other long-running actions (perhaps something computationally intensive). Deferreds also give a clean syntax for waiting for multiple events to complete. If I had two separate AJAX requests, I could wait for both of them via `$.when(jqxhr1,jqxhr2).then(…)`. This allows both requests to complete in parallel, but allows waiting for both to complete before executing a callback.

Answer (score 2):

Basically if you wanted to use the deferred method you'd assign your AJAX request to a variable.

```
var request = $.ajax({ /* Make ajax goodness */ });
```

Then you can reference this using the deferred object.

```
$.when( request ).then(function() {

    // Success

});
```

But to my knowledge they are the same...I'll check the docs and update if I'm incorrect.

Comment: I think the key is the .when method.  It fires after all the others have completed.