# Should I use .done() and .fail() for new jQuery AJAX code instead of success and error

Tags: jquery

I have coded like this:

```
$.ajax({ cache: false,
    url: "/Admin/Contents/GetData",
    data: { accountID: AccountID },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#CityID').html(data);
    },
    error: function (ajaxContext) {
        alert(ajaxContext.responseText)
    }
});
```

But when I look at the jQuery [`.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) at the end it seems to suggest I should be coding like this below or at least it suggests adding a `.done()` and a `.fail()`:

```
var request = $.ajax({ cache: false,
    url: "/Admin/Contents/GetData",
    data: { accountID: AccountID }
});

request.done(function (data) {
    xxx;
});
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    xxx;
});
```

**Update**

If I code like this is it the same or is there some advantage to breaking it into three ?

```
$.ajax({ cache: false,
    url: "/Admin/Contents/GetData",
    data: { accountID: AccountID }
}).done(function (data) {
    xxx;
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    xxx;
});
```

Answer (score 195, accepted):

As stated by user2246674, using `success` and `error` as parameter of the ajax function is valid.

To be consistent with precedent answer, reading the doc :

> **Deprecation Notice**:
>
> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

If you are using the callback-manipulation function (using method-chaining for example), use `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.always()` instead of `success()`, `error()` and `complete()`.

Comment: This is what I thought but when I posted a few questions about status code earlier nobody was mentioning this even after I did.

Comment: @Gemma Trust the Dev team, if they say that it may be removed in future versions and that it's better to use the new ones, use the new ones.

Comment: thanks and yes I will use the new way. Did you see my update at the end. I am wondering if my last code snippet is the best way to do it. I am not sure what the advantage of breaking up the code into three is.

Comment: @Gemma it'll do the same thing, it's a coding technique called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining, there's pros and cons about using it. You may look at this for information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not

Comment: I disagree. The references talks about the *callback-manipulation functions* (e.g. `.error`, `.success`) which *are* deprecated in favor of the more universal Deferred pattern, but the *parameters to the `ajax` method are not deprecated* and are both valid and acceptable - even in jQuery 1.9/2.0! In all current forms, `ajax` still returns a Deferred; possibly with already-attached Deferred callbacks.

Comment: @user2246674 you're right, it's been a while I must have misread the question. I corrected the answer, feel free to enhance it if you think it should.

Comment: Here it is, jQuery 1.9, and success:, error:, and complete: are still usable. However, my question is, is .done() == to success: ?

Comment: @GregoryLewis From JQuery 1.10 source code : `jqXHR.success = jqXHR.done;`.

Comment: I'd honestly prefer `success`, `fail`, `always`.

Comment: WOW, I misread the documentation as well. I literally thought the 'success'/'error' options for $.ajax were rewritten to 'done/fail'. It was just the callback method chains. Honestly, I think they should have switched the option names as well. That had me stumped for hours.

Comment: I want to know the same for jQuery 3.x version. Should I use done() & fail() or then() and catch() ?

Comment: Can anyone please share official documentation for this? I tried google and their official site and failed.

Answer (score 15):

I want to add something on @Michael Laffargue's post:

`jqXHR.done()` is faster!

`jqXHR.success()` have some load time in callback and sometimes can overkill script. I find that on hard way before.

**UPDATE:**

Using `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()` and `jqXHR.always()` you can better manipulate with ajax request. Generaly you can define ajax in some variable or object and use that variable or object in any part of your code and get data faster. Good example:

```
/* Initialize some your AJAX function */
function call_ajax(attr){
    var settings=$.extend({
        call            : 'users',
        option          : 'list'
    }, attr );

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "//exapmple.com//ajax.php",
        data: settings,
        cache : false
    });
}

/* .... Somewhere in your code ..... */

call_ajax({
    /* ... */
    id : 10,
    option : 'edit_user'
    change : {
          name : 'John Doe'
    }
    /* ... */
}).done(function(data){

    /* DO SOMETHING AWESOME */

});
```

Comment: Do you have any  credible and verifiable references?

Comment: @PaulVargas I never do some performance test but in my practice I find this to work. You can try by yourself.

Comment: Please provide any evidence which is trustful.

Comment: Like you know, callback functions are slower compared to return some objects from the function. Sometimes is small impact but sometimes can be huge if you have many calls.

Answer (score 14):

In simple words

```
$.ajax("info.txt").done(function(data) {
  alert(data);
}).fail(function(data){
  alert("Try again champ!");
});
```

if its get the info.text then it will alert and whatever function you add or if any how unable to retrieve info.text from the server then alert or error function.

Answer (score 3):

We will use .done, .fail instead of success, error when we migrate to jQuery from 1.x to 2.x or 3.x in our old existing application because jQuery is going to deprecate these methods. For example, when we make a call to server web methods and the server then returns promise objects to the calling methods (Ajax methods) these promise objects contain .done, .fail, etc. methods. Hence, we will do the same for the success and failure response. Below is an example (it is for a POST request the same way we can construct for a request type like GET...):

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: '{"name" :"sheo"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            cache: false
            }).done(function (Response) {
                  //do something when get response            })
           .fail(function (Response) {
                    //do something when any error occurs.
                });
```