# Success and Error functions not firing in Ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Below is an Ajax call I'm using to determine which menu options to show to users (I know it's a flawed method, just up against a time crunch for a demo). When the page loads, I can step through the controller method in Visual Studio so I know it's hitting the controller and sending back the right information.

Looking at Chrome's Network console I can also see that the browser received the right response. However, neither the `console.log` or the `alert` are firing. Nothing in the `success` or `error` methods is executed either. Does anyone see what's going wrong?

**View**

```
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        //Determine which links to show in navbar
        window.onload = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("CheckSecurity","Home")',
                dataType: 'json',
                succcess: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data);
                    if (data == "admin") { $('#adminLink').show(); }
                    else if (data == "IT") { $('#ITLink').show(); }
                    else if (data == "viewer") { $('#viewerLink').show(); }
                    else if (data == "modifier") { $('#modifierLink').show(); }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        };
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult CheckSecurity()
    {
        if (Security.IsAdmin(User)) return Json("admin", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        if (Security.IsItSupport(User)) return Json("IT", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        if (Security.IsViewer(User)) return Json("viewer", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        if (Security.IsModifier(User)) return Json("modifier", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return Json("NA", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here are a couple screen shots of the Network and regular console in Chrome. Bother are from after I've stepped through the controller method and the program has returned a value back to the browser.

**Network Console**

[image]

**Standard Console**

[image]

Comment: If neither success nor error are being triggered and the server is receiving the request, there must an error in your console, somewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an extra `c` in your

**succcess:**

So the response is a 200 request , but because you have `no mapping for success` defined, it is just never logged

Comment: Ah, so `success` IS being called, but `succcess` isnt. :p

Comment: sweet, thank you! (figured i just needed another pair of eyes :)

Answer (score 4):

It is **success** instead of **succcess**

NealR

### **Deprecation Notice:**

> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks
>   will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their
>   eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always()
>   instead.

### **Check the done, fail and always callbacks below.**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your Url',
    data: JSON.stringify(Parameter list),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    debugger;
}).fail(function (data) {
    debugger;
}).always(function(data) { 
    alert("complete"); 
});
```

### **.ajax().always(function(a, textStatus, b){});**

Replaces method .complete() which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.
 In response to successful transaction, arguments are same as .done() (ie. a = data, b = jqXHR) and for failed transactions the arguments are same as .fail() (ie. a = jqXHR, b = errorThrown).
 This is an alternative construct for the complete callback function above. Refer to **[deferred.always()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)** for implementation details.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your Url',
    data: JSON.stringify(Parameter list),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
    }
}).always(function(data) { 
    alert("complete"); 
});
```

### **.ajax().done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){});**

Replaces method .success() which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.
 This is an alternative construct for the success callback function above. Refer to **[deferred.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)** for implementation details.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your Url',
    data: JSON.stringify(Parameter list),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    debugger;
});
```

### **.ajax().fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){});**

Replaces method .error() which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.
 This is an alternative construct for the complete callback function above. Refer to **[deferred.fail()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/)** for implementation details.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your Url',
    data: JSON.stringify(Parameter list),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
    }
}).fail(function (data) {
    debugger;
});
```

### **[Check here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931891/2377970)**

### **[Check here for the documentation details](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/49)**