# ajaxComplete not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this problem where not all of my `ajaxComplete` calls are getting fired.

My Code

```
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
    $.blockUI();
 })
.ajaxComplete(function () {
    $.unblockUI();
 });
```

Here's the code where `ajaxComplete` didn't fire :

```
$('body').on('click', '.actTimeSheetApprove', function () {
    var node = $(this).parents('tr');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/TimeSheet/Approve/',
        type: 'POST',
        context: this,
        data: {
            __RequestVerificationToken: fnGetToken(),
            id: $(this).data('id')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'success') {
                var table = $('#tblTimeSheetApprove').DataTable();
                table.row(node).remove().draw();
                console.log('SUCCESS'); //I already made sure this is called
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Note that I already make sure `SUCCESS` log is called.

Any idea why?

UPDATE :

Here's my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ClaimAuthorize("Role", "Manager")]
public ActionResult Approve(int id)
{
    _uow.TimeSheet.Approve(id, User.Identity.Name);
    _uow.Save();
    return Content("success");
}
```

And here's my console log :

[image]

Comment: is there any error in your browser console

Comment: Any js error in console: `var node = $(this).parents('tr');` i feel this should have some issue.

Comment: Check in your Dev Tools (F12) Console Tab, if there's any JS error  (or) in your Network Tab if your POST call actually succeeded.

Comment: no, there is no error. Everything is working fine like I said 'SUCCESS' log is showing in my console.

Comment: I just update my post along with browser console log.

Comment: Oops ! Looks like I misunderstood your question :) Your issue is that `ajaxComplete` is not invoked even though you registered on document. One quick question, are you registering this `ajaxComplete` before your `.actTimeSheetApprove`'s click handler in code ?

Comment: does your `$.blockUI();` is getting invoked on start of your Ajax call?

Comment: @vijayP: Yes, `$.blockUI();` is called but `$.unblockUI()` isn't

Comment: What is the version of jQuery that you're using ?

Comment: @Arkantos: jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: could you please add some `console.log` inside `ajaxComplete` before ` $.unblockUI();`

Comment: @vijayP: Yes I already tried that, it's not getting called.

Comment: okay so I found the problem, it is working if I remove `table.row(node).remove().draw();`. So it probably have something to do with `datatables` plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you have incorrect the "syntax" in the `$.ajax` call, you miss the `complete`...

`success !== complete`

https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

With ajaxStart you can use `load` or `ajaxSetup` for make the request and define the behaviour of the success/error methods;

Also for debug, try to `ajaxStop()` and see if everything works well.

Comment: yes, It's a way of doing it. Probably it's old? @Jai

Comment: Its use is not recommended.

Comment: sorry but I don't get it, what do you mean by `success !== complete`? The success function works fine, it's just that my ajaxComplete is not firing.

Comment: I mean, if you change the success for the complete:
 ```$.ajax({
        url: '/TimeSheet/Approve/',
        type: 'POST',
        context: this,
        data: {
            __RequestVerificationToken: fnGetToken(),
            id: $(this).data('id')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'success') {
                var table = $('#tblTimeSheetApprove').DataTable();
                table.row(node).remove().draw();
                console.log('SUCCESS'); //I already made sure this is called
            }
        }
    })```

Answer (score -1):

Check the done, fail and always callbacks below.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Your Url',
    data: JSON.stringify(Parameter list),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    debugger;
}).fail(function (data) {
    debugger;
}).always(function(data) { 
    alert("complete"); 
});
```

**.ajax().always(function(a, textStatus, b){});**

Replaces method .complete() which was deprecated in jQuery 1.8. In response to successful transaction, arguments are same as .done() (ie. a = data, b = jqXHR) and for failed transactions the arguments are same as .fail() (ie. a = jqXHR, b = errorThrown). This is an alternative construct for the complete callback function above. Refer to deferred.always() for implementation details.

please check this link : [firing in Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552273/success-and-error-functions-not-firing-in-ajax-call)