# Why do I hit error in AJAX file upload with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am working on a multiple file uploader using HTML5's FormData and jQuery. I have the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#file').bind("change", function() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        //loop for add $_FILES["upload"+i] to formData
        for (var i = 0, len = document.getElementById('file').files.length; i < len; i++) {
            formData.append("file" + i, document.getElementById('file').files[i]);
        }

        //send formData to server-side
        $.ajax({
            url : "file-upload.php",
            type : 'post',
            data : formData,
            dataType : 'json',
            async : true,
            processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            error : function(request) {
                alert('error!!');
                console.log(request.responseText);
            },
            success : function(json) {
                alert('success!!');
                $('#upload-result')[0].append(json);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I can see that my `file-upload.php` works fine because the files are uploaded! But **why does my jQuery hit the error function and not the success function**? I get an alert of Error.

In the console window, I see the result of my PHP echo call! Which I want to append to `#upload-result` as shown in my success function.

**PHP code**

```
foreach($_FILES as $index => $file)
{
    $fileName     = $file['name'];
    // echo '[ file name: ' . $fileName . ' - ';
    $fileTempName = $file['tmp_name'];
    // echo 'file temp name: ' . $fileTempName . ' ]';

    if(!empty($file['error'][$index]))
    {
        // some error occured with the file in index $index
        // yield an error here
        return false; // return false also immediately perhaps??
    }

    // check whether it's not empty, and whether it indeed is an uploaded file
    if(!empty($fileTempName) && is_uploaded_file($fileTempName))
    {
        // the path to the actual uploaded file is in $_FILES[ 'file' ][ 'tmp_name' ][ $index ]
        // do something with it:
        move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, "uploads/" . $fileName);
        echo json_encode('<p>Click <a href="'. 'uploads/' . $fileName . '">here</a> to download file!</p>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what is the error.?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Reload the page. What does the JavaScript console say? Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct?

Comment: can you print the request.responseText

Comment: The definition of the jQuery error function is: `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`. **Look at the third argument**, what error is jQuery reporting?

Comment: updated question with console output.

Comment: Aside from the text, your php script must return a 200 status code. Does it ?

Comment: yes it does, I see that in Chrome's Dev Tools under Network tab.

Comment: please show the code file-upload.php

Comment: added php code as requested.

Comment: Take the error event out of the params object and use .done() and .fail()

Comment: @ovi what do you mean? Can you please provide an example? Thanks

Comment: Implement like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931836/should-i-use-done-and-fail-for-new-jquery-ajax-code-instead-of-success-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was getting the jQuery AJAX error even though my status code was 200 for the php file **because** I had my `dataType` as JSON, whilst I was returning simple HTML.

```
dataType: 'html',
```

Fixed it!

Thanks all.