# How to pass Rails controller varaible to AJAX call in form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller, instance-variables

Say you have the following code:

```
# foobars_controller.rb
class FoobarController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @foobar = Foobar.new
    @other_var = 123
    ...
  end
end
```

---

```
# _form.html.erb for foobar
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: some.route.to.function
      data: {
        other_var: ?????
        ...
      }
    })
  });
</script>

<html>
  <!-- @other_var is visible here, I just need to get it into the AJAX call, above -->
</html>
```

My question is this:  What is the best way to get the value in the *controller's* @other_var instance variable into the *view's* AJAX call?  I know that instance variables defined in the controller are available in the view files, but I'm not clear how to access that variable from inside the javascript/JQuery.

#### ***Edit:

I see that there are some options for chaining method calls in .ajax, and/or using one AJAX call to get the other_var from the controller, then using another AJAX call to send that value to the original URL of interest.  I'll look at ways to make this do what I need.

It still seems like there should be an easier way.  The javascript/JQuery is in the view file that has access to the controller instance variables.  Is there no way to stuff that variable's value into a form element and then access it there when I need to use it in the AJAX call?

Comment: Returning a json document??

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: This is your first time using ajax??

Comment: Pretty close.  Definitely the first time in Rails.

Comment: That's it...look you can return from the controller a json document with the relevant data....then in the ajax call you have two options to treat the returning json, in the success or in the done call...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931836/should-i-use-done-and-fail-for-new-jquery-ajax-code-instead-of-success-and

Comment: So, basically you suggest breaking this into two AJAX calls - the first to the controller to get the variable value, and the second to the main function, using the value retrieved in the first?

Comment: Not two ajax calls, just one, like this: `$.ajax({
      url: some.route.to.function
      data: {
        other_var: ?????
        ...
      }
    }).done(function(response){//here response if the data from your controller});`

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear exactly how this would work.  The done function is executed AFTER the AJAX call, right?  I need to get the other_var value BEFORE I send it off with the AJAX call.  Also, retrieving the other_var value from the controller requires a different URL than the actual AJAX call I want to make. Wouldn't that mean it needs its own AJAX call?  It looks like the done() method just executes a javascript function, not that it goes to a URL for something.