# unable to get ajax done works

Tags: ajax, json, tornado

ajax done doesnt fire when receive json file. it prints json object out
client side

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: data
            }).done(function() {
                console.log( "Sample of data:");
                alert("hello");
            }).fail(function()  {
                console.log("ajax failed ");
            });
```

on service side, I got json file from client

```
 def post(self):
    print self.request.body
    print tornado.escape.json_encode(self.request.body)
    self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    self.write("{}")
```

on browser , I didnt see any error code. i get 200. but console output "ajax failed"
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         processData: false,
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         data: data,
         success: function(){
             console.log( "Sample of data:");
             alert("hello");
               },
         error: function()  {
            console.log("ajax failed ");
           }
       });
```

Comment: success and error will be replaced by done, fail. right?

Comment: yes just as I wrote up there. Use the success and error attributes instead of done and fail

Comment: "done is the preferred way to implement success callbacks" from jquery site

Comment: ok, your way works well but I don't understand why "done" doesn't work

Comment: That's a good question, have a look a this related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931836/should-i-use-done-and-fail-for-new-jquery-ajax-code-instead-of-success-and

Comment: The .success() callback is the one that is discouraged and deprecated but not the success: attribute. Which is why it still works on jQuery-latest

Comment: thanks, I got confused about success attribute and success call back. I am sill waiting for answer of "done" :)

Comment: I'd be interested to see that answer as well :)

Comment: I just change back to my origin copy which it post on my question. it works now. I have no ideal why it doesnt work before :(

Comment: Strange... I hate it when that hapens. Happy coding!

Comment: I am new to web programming. it must be some cache stuff.. do I need to clear cache everytime?