# Cordova App For WIndows 8.1 App Error in Ajax Reuqest

Tags: jquery, windows, cordova, knockout.js

I have the following Ajax call in my Cordova App which i am building in VS2015 for WIndows App and the Fuction Success Result continues to return Null.. This used to work before in the previous version of Cordova.

```
self.displayPicture = function () {
    self.message('Loading Image');
    self.showLoading(true);

    var server = getUploadsResource();
    var url = server + '/' + self.id();
    var Token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: url,
        headers: { deviceHeaderStorage: Token }
    }).done(function (successResult) {


        self.showLoading(false);
        self.showImage(true);
        self.ithasImage(true);
        self.hasChanges(false);
        self.hasNotImage(false);
        self.previewImage(false);
        self.showDelete(true);
        self.imageSrc("data:image/jpeg;base64," + successResult.Data);
        self.currentImage(successResult.Data);

    }).fail(function (errorResult) {
        self.showLoading(false);
        var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Error");
        messageDialog.showAsync();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following ajax layout instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: url,
    headers: { deviceHeaderStorage: Token },
    success: function (successResult){
        //Success Code Here
    }
    error: function(co, responseObj){
        //Error Handling here
    }
});
```

Furthermore, to borrow from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931836/should-i-use-done-and-fail-for-new-jquery-ajax-code-instead-of-success-and):

> **Deprecation Notice:**
>
> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: I tried this method as well but nothing, i think it might be knockout thats giving these issues.... Hate it