# Display a spinner while sending a sync Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spinner, synchronous

I need to display a spinner while sending a synchronous Ajax request to the server to retrieve data.

I know it is better to do it in asynchronous mode but I'm not allow to do it.
I also know sync ajax request blocks the browser.

I already found a solution with a setTimeout to delay the call of my ajax request but my boss doesn't want me to use setTimeout.

Do you have any solution to solve my problem please ? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Jquery has some ajax event handlers. You can use

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( "#loading" ).show();
});
```

to show the loading image when sending the request and

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( "#loading" ).hide();
});
```

to hide the loading image when the request is complete.

REF: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ and http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of AJAX `beforeSend` `success` `error` or `complete` function. Or you can simply show a spinner before AJAX call and hide it in your `success` or `error` or `complete` function depending on your requirement.

Sample Code :

```
  $('.spinner-div').show();
  $.ajax({
  //You AJAX function
  success: function(){
     $('.spinner-div').hide();
     //Show success message
  },
  error : function(){
     $('.spinner-div').hide();
     //Show error message
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a .success() method on ajax requests.

heres some examples of how it can be used
[jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

There is some debate about deprication here though
[Should I use .done() and .fail() for new jQuery AJAX code instead of success and error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931836/should-i-use-done-and-fail-for-new-jquery-ajax-code-instead-of-success-and)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply `show` your spinner before your AJAX call, then `hide` it inside the `success` & `error` of your AJAX call :

```js
$('#spinner').show(); //Show your spinner before the AJAX call
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  method: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    $('#spinner').hide(); //Hide your spinner after your call
  },
  error: function(){
    setTimeout(() => { //I'm setting a setTimeout here so you have the time to see the spinner.
                       // Remove it when you copy this code.

      $('#spinner').hide(); //Hide your spinner after your call
    },2000);
  }
});
```

```css
#spinner{
  display: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spinner">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by rendering a 'static' gif to the page, and making your script replace the content of the div with the results of the AJAX call.
This will effectively show a 'loading' icon until the results load, but if there is an error from your script then the gif will spin forever.

```
            <div id="chart_score" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
                <div style="text-align: center; height: 100%;">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <img src="../../Img/GIF/CircleLoader.gif" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    Loading chart...
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solutions above (which I already had, but didn't work):

I had `async:false,` in my ajax call that I had copied from some example, which of course breaks the simultaneous front-end spinner update. A no-brainer when you think about it, but it was nowhere explicitly shown in the above examples.

So, `async:true` finally fixed it.