# How to return a ajax result to global variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a pagination using jquery. I want to return a ajax success response to global Variable.
I have created a global variable and stored the response. But I cannot access outside of success block. I want to change the value dynamically, because it will retrive the data when I click the next page without refresh. Thanks in advance..

Code :

```
  var tmp;
     $('table').DataTable ({
        serverSide:true,
        ajax : {
            url:'http://localhost:8000/api/feeds/1/',
            type:'GET',                
        },drawCallback : function(settings) {

          var api = this.api();
          tmp = api.rows({page:'current'}).data();

        }
      });
    console.log(tmp);
```

Comment: this is because ajax is an async call, whereas javascript is synchronous, meaning, your `console.log` gets executed before `tmp` gets assigned. perhaps you could wrap this in a promise, or modify/access `tmp` from your success callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I can't understand about promise. How to handle promise for my problem?

Comment: you can read this for promise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931836/should-i-use-done-and-fail-for-new-jquery-ajax-code-instead-of-success-and

Comment: remove var... only put tmp = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I have wrapped your request with promise. as suggested by @Napoli in comments

```
function loadTable(){ 
  $('table').DataTable ({
    serverSide:true,
    ajax : {
      url:'http://localhost:8000/api/feeds/1/',
      type:'GET',                
    },
    drawCallback : function(settings) {
      var api = this.api();
      tmp = api.rows({page:'current'}).data();
      console.log("from api :", tmp);
      return Promise.resolve(tmp);
    },
    error : function( xhr, textStatus, error ) {
      console.log("error", xhr, textStatus, error);
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  });
}

loadTable.then(data => console.log("outside loadTable()",data));
```

I havn't tested this yet, this is just to give you a clear idea.