# Getting undefined in callback function in cross domain ajax post

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to make ajax post request to my flask app and get the answer in the callback function. Unfortunately I got undefined value instead of a json.

Will appreciate any help!

My server-side code:

```
application = Flask(__name__)
CORS(application)

...

@application.route('/get_forecast', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_forecast():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('in post')
        predictions = {} 
        predictions['data'] = calc_forecast(request.get_json()["data"])
        print(predictions)
        return jsonify(predictions)
```

my client-side code:

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "http://localhost:5000/get_forecast",
            data: JSON.stringify(markers),
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            done: function(resp, status){
                console.log('done')
                console.log(resp)
                console.log(status)
                console.log('=====')
                }(),
            fail: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log('fail');
                console.log(thrownError)
                }()

        });
```

Here's what I got in the flask terminal:

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2018 12:59:53] "OPTIONS /get_forecast HTTP/1.1" 200 -
in post
{'data': [10.15451836569513, 56.578480707072714, 12.435548873275337]}
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2018 12:59:53] "POST /get_forecast HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Here's what I got in the chrome console:

```
demo.html:228 done
demo.html:229 undefined
demo.html:230 undefined
demo.html:231 =====
demo.html:234 fail
demo.html:235 undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the examples over at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ they look quite a bit different from your call to `$.ajax`. I adjusted your code to better resemble the examples. Maybe this helps?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://localhost:5000/get_forecast",
    data: JSON.stringify(markers),
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json"
    })
    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('done');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log('=====');
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('fail');
        console.log(textStatus);
    });
```

I think, you were looking for `success` and `error` settings.

---

**Update:** Yes, I'm pretty sure, your settings `done` and `fail` are wrong. You want to use `success` and `error`.

Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931891/1621041

This means, your code could also look like this, if you want to put everything into the settings of the `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://localhost:5000/get_forecast",
    data: JSON.stringify(markers),
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('done');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log('=====');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        console.log('fail');
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```