# Laravel Validation via Ajax: How to show error message in blade

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-validation

I want to validate NID number is exists or not. I want this validation on key up via AJax. 
I didn't work to show errors in ajax before. I write these codes in Jquery. Please help me if I have any mistakes.

in blade

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="nid" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
        NID Number<sup class="text-danger">*</sup>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control {!! $errors->has('nid_number') ? 'is-invalid' : 'is-valid' !!}"
               placeholder="ভোটার আইডি" id="nid"
               name="nid_number" value="{{ old('nid_number') }}">
        @error('nid_number')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery cdn

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

ajax code

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#nid', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('ajax-validation') }}",
        method:'POST',
        data:{query:$(this).val()},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    })
});
```

in controller

```
public function ajaxValidation(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nid_number' => 'unique:members',
        ]);
    }
}
```

I think this validate() returns errors automatically. that's why I didn't use any `return json_enconde()`
Now help me How can I show errors now. Thanks in advance. And sorry for your time.

Comment: This is some link that could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931836/should-i-use-done-and-fail-for-new-jquery-ajax-code-instead-of-success-and

Modifiying the way you do your ajax request and using the ```.fail()``` will ease your way to display errors.

Comment: Return output from `ajaxValidation` via json. And catch it with ajax and show the error

Comment: how can I return errors from validate($request)? Can you please tell me? @TalhaF.

Comment: Please provide your JSON response code from `ajaxValidation`

Comment: I just want to check that NID is existed or not. 
```if ($request->ajax()) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nid_number' => 'unique:members',
        ]);
    }```
that is the validation code. It automatically return errors when I normally submit the form. but I dont know how to send errors in json, that's why I asked.

Comment: Check `request` from your browser and see the output.

Comment: As further I know, laravel `validation` send data by SESSION in server side.

Comment: yeah right.....

Comment: I think, my flow of validation using ajax was wrong. Can you suggest me any documents to check live validation using ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your ajax part you are missing error portion**

```
error:function(data)
{
   console.log(data);
}
```

*This is the portion where you will receive laravel validation errors, which will be something like `console.log(data.responseJSON.errors)` not really sure for this piece of code but you can find in your console. In success method you will never receive validation errors. After that you can play with errors to include in your form inputs*

Answer (score 1):

You can check validation like this :

```
public function ajaxValidation(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'nid_number' => 'unique:members',
        ]);
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            return response()->json(['status' => '1']); // success
        }
        return response()->json(['status' => '0'); // not success
    }
```

Comment: then How to handle from ajax? In ajax its always say error
here is the updated ajax code,
`$(document).on('keyup', '#nid', function () {
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('ajax-validation') }}",
                method: 'POST',
                data: {query: $(this).val()},
            }).fail(function () {
                alert('error');
            }).done(function () {
                alert('done')
            });
        });`

Comment: it always go on .`fail()`

Comment: just checked the console. `dd($request)` is null.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ajax in this answer, but if anyone wonders how to get laravel error/success sessions with javascript, here is a hack

```html
@if (session('success'))
<div class="form-success text-white" hidden aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="absolute">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

and in javascript

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    let FormSuccess = document.querySelector(".form-success");
    if (FormSuccess) {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Successful",
            text: FormSuccess.textContent,
        });
    }
});
```

then in your controller or service just do

```
return redirect()->route("name")->with("register_success","Registered succesfully!");
```